# c - in_addr_t variable as paramether of connect

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ip-address

I have a variable of `in_addr_t` type and I would like to use `connect()` with the given ip. I'm therefore needing a `(struct sockaddr *)` variable as parameter for the `connect()`. How to insert use the `in_addr_t` variable instead?

```
in_addr_t var; // Given variable, not actually declared here ofc

int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in *srvraddr = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
memset((void *) srvraddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
srvraddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
srvraddr->sin_port = htons(PORT_A); // Big - little endian arch compatibility

srvraddr->sin_addr.s_addr = var; // Somehow assign var here? <<<<<

connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) srvraddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

Whatever I try to do connect always returns me `-1`.
Using `perror` I get the following error: `Connection refused`.

Comment: Why the `(struct sockaddr *)` cast?  `srvraddr` is a pointer to `struct sockaddr_in` data, not `struct sockaddr` as expected in `int connect(int socket, const struct sockaddr *address,
socklen_t address_len)`.

Comment: Yes and no, @chux.  The form the OP presents for his `connect()` call is absolutely normal and expected usage for POSIX `connect()`.  In practice, that function accepts pointers to various different kinds of address structures, as described by POSIX this way: "The length and format of the address depend on the address family of the socket."  This *does* violate the strict aliasing rule, but it must nevertheless work in C implementations that conform to POSIX.

Comment: When your `connect()` call returns -1, it should also set `errno` appropriately.  That tells you the nature of the error.  Although you could look up the value in a table, I'd recommending just using `perror()` to get a human-readable explanation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added result of the perror!

Comment: @JohnBollinger Would not a union of `struct sockaddr` and `struct sockaddr_in` meet POSIX requirements, not violate the strict aliasing rule and avoid casts?

Comment: I guess it would, @chux, but that doesn't change the fact that the form the OP presents is utterly conventional.

Comment: @chux If you can make sense of the GNU/Linux `sys/socket.h`, it seems a union is used in that implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to insert use the `in_addr_t` variable instead?

You cannot use an `in_addr_t` with `connect()` instead of a `struct sockaddr_in`.  `connect()` accepts varying address structure types, but not arbitrary ones.  The correct structure type for an IPv4 address is the `struct sockaddr_in` that you're already using.  You need to store an appropriate representation of the remote host address into that.

Evidently, you already have an `in_addr_t` that you assert represents the remote address, but are uncertain how to use it:

> ```
> in_addr_t var; // Given variable, not actually declared here ofc
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> srvraddr->sin_addr.s_addr = var; // Somehow assign var here? <<<<<
> ```

What you present is already exactly what POSIX expects you to do, however.  POSIX requires that the `sin_addr` member of a `struct sockaddr_in` be a structure having at minimum a `s_addr` member of type `in_addr_t`.  Supposing that the `in_addr_t` you have is in fact a correct representation of the machine address to which you want to connect, assigning that value to `sin_addr.s_addr` of your address structure is just right.  In principle, there could be more members of that struct, but in practice, implementations that want to be interoperable will not require you to set any other members.  Most don't have other members at all.

Do note, however, that just because `connect()` receives the address structure via a pointer does not mean you need to use dynamic allocation.  It would be a bit more idiomatic to do this:

```
int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in srvraddr = { 0 };

srvraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
srvraddr.sin_port = htons(PORT_A);
srvraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = var;

connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &srvraddr, sizeof(srvraddr));
```

Among other things, that saves you having to free the memory afterward.

> Whatever I try to do connect always returns me -1. Using perror I get the following error: Connection refused.

As far as I can see, the code you've presented is fine.  You may want to check how you are obtaining the `in_addr_t` value in the first place, and to verify the port number you are using.  On the other hand, do not overlook the possibility that the problem is at the remote host: perhaps the port you are trying to connect to is just not open (to you).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, indeed the problem was with the `in_addr_t` I was using, not with the block of code I posted. At this point I'm not sure my question should be kept on stackoverflow... in any case your answer was correct so I marked it :)

Answer (score -1):

This is my way of using connect() to get a connection to "example.com" on port 80:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  int sockfd;

  if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "socket");
    return 0;
  }

  char domain[] = "example.com";
  struct hostent *he;
  he = gethostbyname (domain);
  if (!he)
  {
    switch (h_errno)
    {
    case HOST_NOT_FOUND:
      fputs ("The host was not found.\n", stderr);
      break;
    case NO_ADDRESS:
      fputs ("The name is valid but it has no address.\n", stderr);
      break;
    case NO_RECOVERY:
      fputs ("A non-recoverable name server error occurred.\n", stderr);
      break;
    case TRY_AGAIN:
      fputs ("The name server is temporarily unavailable.", stderr);
      break;
    }
    return 1;
  }
  if (he->h_length < 4)
    return 1;

  struct sockaddr_in srvraddr;
  srvraddr.sin_len = sizeof(srvraddr);
  srvraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  srvraddr.sin_port = htons(80);

  srvraddr.sin_addr = * (struct in_addr *) he->h_addr_list[0];

  if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&srvraddr, srvraddr.sin_len) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"connect() failed\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Use conection here...

  close(sockfd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Declaring `srvraddr` as `sockaddr` is wrong. You need to use `sockaddr_in` instead, that is what `connect()` expects for an `AF_INET` address, eg: `struct sockaddr_in srvraddr; srvraddr.sin_len = sizeof(srvraddr); srvraddr.sin_family = AF_INET; srvraddr.sin_port = htons(80); srvraddr.sin_addr = * (in_addr*) he->h_addr; connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&srvraddr, sizeof(srvraddr))` This will also allow you to migrate to IPv6 someday, by simply switching from `sockaddr_in` to `sockaddr_in6` (and you should be using `getaddrinfo()` instead of `gethostbyname()`).

Comment: My initial code wasn't wrong, and worked fine. Although not guaranteed to work with possible future changes in struct sockaddr, which I don't think there will be any for IPv4. Be that as it may, I updated the code. Although didn't bother to use getaddrinfo().

Comment: FYI, the 3rd parameter of `socket()` is a protocol ID, not an address family.  `AF_NS` is an address family, like `AF_INET` is.  You should not be passing `AF_NS` in that parameter.  It just happens that `AF_NS` is defined as 6, which is the same value as `IPPROTO_TCP`. Pass that instead to `socket()`.